# Action delegate with more than four parameters (method arguments)

Tags: c#, delegates

I have written a helper class which uses the Action - delegate as method parameter.
Like this:
`public void SomeMethod(Action<T> methodToExecute, T argument);`

According to the MSDN you can declare max. 4 arguments on an action delegate: `Action<T1,T2,T3,T4>`.

Now I'd like to call a method which needs 5! arguments. How could I do this?
The best solution would be something where I could use a dynamic number of method arguments.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should think about grouping some of those arguments into a specific type.

Comment: That's true. It is not very clever. But the situation is that I cannot introduce a new type or so. I have to offer this method accepting 5 or more params.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Declare the action delegate you need, there's nothing magic about it:

```
public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 p1, T2 p2, T3 p3, T4 p4, T5 p5);
```

Comment: When .NET4 arrives the built-in `Action` and `Func` delegates will allow up to 16 parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402872(VS.100).aspx

Comment: I'm sorry but the following method signature does not compile:

public static void Throws<TException, TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFourth, TFifth>(Action<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFourth,TFifth> methodToExecute, TFirst first, TSecond second, TThird third, TFourth forth, TFifth fifth) where TException : System.Exception
  { /// some code }

It tells me: "The non-generic type'System.Action' cannot be used with type arguments."

Comment: And did you declare the Action delegate with five generic types?

Comment: The declaration was wrong. Typing is hard ;-) Now it is accepted and I can use it.
Anyway, next time I need e.g. 6 params I have to declare another new delegate an so on. How could we make this more felxible?

Comment: Define all those delegates in your class library so that they're there the next time you need them. Unfortunately there is no way for generics in .NET or C# to handle an unlimited number of type arguments.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately ... But I can live with that.
I have to look that my "customer" improves his code. They like to declare methods with thousands of parameters instead of using suitable classes.